# css text-shadow differences in chrome and mozilla

Tags: css, font-size

Lets say I want to add shadow to a text of size 33 px.
The unit I prefer for shadows is em as I want the shadows to scale when the page is browser zoomed.

I want my shadow **fuzziness to be 2px**. So my em value is 2/33 =0.0606 em.
So,

```
text-shadow: 0em 0em 0.0606em black;
```

Bu there is a problem!The value 0.0606 is not exact **(2/33 is recurring) 0.0303 is lesser than the actual value**.
Mozilla rounds up the em values to the higher px value. In this case it would remain 2px.
But Chrome rounds it down. So in this case it would be **1px only**.

Now there is a bad disagreement I want to get rid of. How do I?

Comment: Ugh, subpixel rounding differences are a pain aren't they? Can you use a slightly higher value that (hopefully) both browsers will round similarly?

Comment: I second what @JonathanNicol said - this is a great resource about sub-pixel rounding: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
But do mean I should choose a px number that will give a non recurring em value? Like if my font size is 20 px and I want fuzziness to be 2 px I can use 0.1em. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Or are you asking me to use something like 0.6 em (greater than 0.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it may sound redundant by try addressing each browser individually with css. That way the browsers can beat to their own drum. http://davidwalsh.name/css-box-shadow